# Postgres: WHERE... AND syntax problem

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can anyone help with a Postgres syntax problem? I'm trying to insert a record, but before doing so, check it doesn't exist, using `WHERE... AND`.

```
=# \d domes_manor_place;
 id       | integer | not null default nextval('domes_manor_place_id_seq'::regclass)
 manor_id | integer | not null
 place_id | integer | not null
=# select * from domes_manor_place where place_id='13621';                                                                            
 24017 |    22276 |    13621
```

OK, so we know that there is no record with `manor_id=22398` and `place_id=13621`. Let's try to insert it with our `WHERE... AND' syntax:

```
=# INSERT INTO domes_manor_place (manor_id, place_id) SELECT 22398, 13621                                                                 
WHERE (22398 NOT IN (SELECT manor_id FROM domes_manor_place)) AND                                                                             
(13621 NOT IN (SELECT place_id FROM domes_manor_place));
INSERT 0 0
```

It won't insert the record - so what's wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE (22398, 13621) NOT IN (SELECT manor_id, place_id FROM domes_manor_place)
```

By the way, a much better approach is to use a unique constraint on the pair of columns. This will cause the insert to fail if a row already exists.

Comment: There is big difference between the condition in the SELECT and a UNIQUE constraint. The condition doesn't provide any uniqueness at all, different transactions can insert the same data at the same moment.

Answer (score 0):

You need a UNIQUE-constraint, the SELECT can't help because it can't see data that is not committed yet. Different transactions can insert new records at the same moment and these are all "unique"... NOT.